# Podspec subspec where the module name is not the same as the podspec name?

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, cocoapods, xcode7

So I have a project in swift (xcode 7) that has a bunch of framework targets, I want to have one podspec that includes, as subspecs, all of these frameworks.

When I create a podspec and add a bunch of subspecs to a sample project the sample project doesn't compile because the module names have changed.

For example I have a podspec named "Frameworks" with subspecs "Datamodel" and "Common".

I create a sample project with a podfile that has references to both 'Frameworks/Datamodel' and 'Frameworks/Common'. The datamodel framework has dependencies on the common and inside the datamodel code the common framework is imported with

```
import common
```

but in the sample project all of the subspecs are getting inserted into a new framework that cocoapods generates called Frameworks so this import common throws an error saying it can't find the common module. I have to change it to

```
import Framework
```

To get it to work, but that is definitely not an acceptable solution.

How can I resolve this?? Or is this just something I can't do?

Comment: Any progress on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the [`module_name`](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#module_name) attribute. You can add this to your podspec to change how CocoaPods generates your framework.

Comment: I tried that but you can't apply it to sub_specs only the base spec

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: You should submit an issue on [the CocoaPods repo](https://github.com/cocoapods/cocoapods) to get support for this on subspecs.

Comment: any solution to this.?